# Spring 4 MVC mechanism to connect to OAuth2 Provider's URL via HTTP Post

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0

Am using Spring 4 MVC to create RESTful Web Services.

Need to use an HTTP Post to obtain an access token (by passing in an id and secret given from an OAuth provider):

curl command:

```
curl -X POST \
https://api.app.com/v1/oauth/token \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'cliend_id=12354aaa&secret=423aaBCd’
```

MyController:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    private static String url = "https://api.app.com/v1/oauth/token";
    private HttpHeaders headers = null;

    @Autowired
    public MyController() {
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAccessToken", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
    public AccessToken getAccessToken(@RequestParam(value="client_id", required=true) String client_id, @RequestParam(value="secret", required=true) String secret) {
        AccessToken token = // How to get token from the response? 
        return token;
    }
```

}

Tried using this:

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("https://api.app.com/v1/oauth/token");
resourceDetails.setClientId("12354aaa");
resourceDetails.setClientSecret("423aaBCd");
resourceDetails.setGrantType("client_credentials");
resourceDetails.setScope(OAuthUtils.getScopesList("read", "write"));

DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();

oauth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);

OAuth2AccessToken token = oauth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken();
System.out.println(token);
```

This returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" error="access_denied", error_description="Unable to obtain a new access token for resource 'null'. The provider manager is not configured to support it."
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
```

(1) How can I get the accessToken from the OAuth Provider's URL from inside MyController's method?

(2) Is there a better way (Spring library or mechanism) which I can obtain the access token for each subsequent call (for example HTTP GET) like an automatic mechanism?

(3) Should I be using something else like RestTemplate to make these calls?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using RestTemplate
something like that

```
private OAuth2RestTemplate template;

ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("https://api.app.com/v1/oauth/token");
resourceDetails.setClientId(client_id);
resourceDetails.setClientSecret(secret);

resourceDetails.setGrantType("password");
resourceDetails.setUsername("**USERNAME**");
resourceDetails.setPassword("**PASSWORD**");

resourceDetails.setScope(asList("read", "write"));

DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();

template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);

token = template.getAccessToken();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion... Edited my post based on your suggestion and now I get an "access denied" error.

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover Did you figured this out. I am also struck here